# WPF using MVVM Light: How to bind a ContentControl to a child property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm-light

I am trying to implement an intermediary class `ViewModelSelector` that sets up and selects the current View/ViewModel to be shown as part of the main view main window `MainView.xaml`. I am trying to do this by defining a DataTemplate for `ViewModel1` (see below) inside  `MainView.xaml` and then using a `ContentControl` which I bind to the property `CurrentViewModel` of `ViewModelSelector`. The `ViewModelSelector` assigns `ViewModel1` to its property `CurrentViewModel`. The idea is then to extend this with more DataTemplates and ViewModels and using UserControls to have the `ViewModelSelector` setup and decide which ViewModel to show (`ViewModel1`, `ViewModel2`, etc.). However for some reason this is not working:

When binding the ContentControl to `ViewModelSelector.CurrentViewModel` using `<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModelSelector.CurrentViewModel}"/>` the datatemplate is not shown (see `MainView.xaml` below). But no other error is thrown (that I can tell).

For debugging purposes I also created a `CurrentViewModelInMainViewModel` property in `MainViewModel.cs` which I set to `ViewModelSelector.CurrentViewModel` (`CurrentViewModelInMainViewModel = ViewModelSelector.CurrentViewModel;`). Binding directly to it (`<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModelInMainViewModel}"/>`) works and the DataTemplate is shown.

So what am I doing wrong?

Here is the elided code. I hope I did not put any error in it, as I am not at work right now and can't test ...

My `MainViewModel.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ProgramEditor.ViewModel
{
    using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
    using ProgramEditor.View;

    class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    private ViewModelSelector ViewModelSelector;
    public ViewModelSelector ViewModelSelector
    {
        get { return ViewModelSelector; }
        set {
            ViewModelSelector = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ViewModelSelector");
        }
    }

    private ViewModelBase currentViewModelInMainViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModelInMainViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return currentViewModelInMainViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            currentViewModelInMainViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModelInMainViewModel");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ViewModelSelector ViewModelSelector = new ViewModelSelector();
        CurrentViewModelInMainViewModel = ViewModelSelector.CurrentViewModel;
    }
    }
}
```

The class `ViewModelSelector`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ProgramEditor.ViewModel
{
    using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

    class ViewModelSelector : ViewModelBase
    {
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
        if (currentViewModel == value)
            return;
        currentViewModel = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
    private ViewModelBase currentViewModel;

    public ViewModelSelector()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = new ViewModel1();
    }
    }
}
```

The dummy `ViewModel1`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ProgramEditor.ViewModel
{
    using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

    public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase
    {
    }
}



    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:FirstViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="There be dragons here." FontSize="50"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

My `MainView.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="ProgramEditor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ProgramEditor.View"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:ProgramEditor.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="900" Width="1600">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:ViewModel1}">
            <TextBlock Text="There be dragons here." FontSize="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <!-- This works (shows up in main window): -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModelInMainViewModel}"/>
        <!-- This does not work (does not show up in main window): -->
        <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModelSelector.CurrentViewModel}"/>-->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: What is `ViewModelMediator` ? What means *"does not"* works? Exception? Blank screen?

Comment: Property path syntax normally works. But if you use it incorrectly, it won't. Unfortunately, you have provided only an incomplete, not-even-compilable code example and a vague, incomplete problem description. Please improve the question. See [mcve] for information about what a good code example looks like.

Comment: Ok. I redid the question. I thought it was sufficiently self-explanatory and assumed that somebody more familiar with WPF would directly spot the error. I hope the problem is now clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a trivial programming error. I was overriding the `ViewModelSelector` property in the constructor of `MainViewModel.cs` here: `ViewModelSelector ViewModelSelector = new ViewModelSelector();`

After changing that line to `ViewModelSelector = new ViewModelSelector();` it now works as expected.

Comment: My enlightenment: Just another reason to always post the full code, since I did not have that snippet in the original version of the question.